# Eurekalog for Java

Tags: java, delphi, error-handling

I'm looking for a tool like EurekaLog for Delphi, but that works in Java.

What is the best option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java you always have stacktrace with error information. And you just can include some logging tool like log4j.

Answer (score 3):

I am not very knowledgeable with EurekaLog, but for what I have read, it is a sophisticated exception trace utility.

In java, I use Log4j. Capturing the complete stack trace at exception is as easy as `log.error("description",exception)`

Answer (score 1):

As there are surely visitors comming here looking for a solution for android (like me), I additionally would like to point to [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra), an android-only equivalent.